# Clearing Eclipse Subversion password

Tags: eclipse, svn, passwords

Eclipse/Aptana seems to remember my password that I use to access my SVN repositories. Is there a way I can clear the stored passwords?

Comment: Check my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51479457/5089770).

Comment: Check my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51479457/5089770).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

just want to share,
In windows 7 machine, the password is saved at:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple
```

Comment: this one is actually correct, the other linked article doesn't work for win7

Comment: This is also applicable to Windows 8.

Comment: Even shorter: %appdata%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple.

Answer (score 14):

Change the perspective to *SVN Repository Exploring*. 
Inside the *SVN Repositories* view, right click "Location properties... ".  A dialog will open and on the first tab you will be able to change your username and password.

Comment: This isn't an options on Eclipse 3.6.2 with Subclipse 1.6.1.

Answer (score 3):

Delete file from svn.simple folder for that

Go to C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple

After clicking {username} if AppData folder is not visible Then Go Tools-->FolderOptions-->View-->click on show hidden folders button.

Answer (score 3):

With eclipse 4.X on ubuntu you have to remove the file 
[eclipse install folder]/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.keyring

Answer (score 1):

Delete the below files

```
<Your eclipse installation path>\Eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.keyring

C:\Documents and Settings\<your user name>\Application Data\Subversion\auth\svn.simple
```

and restart the eclipse