# How to change user in eclipse svn repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I get eclipse from my friend and his eclipse use his user to communicate with SVN, commit or update. I want to change to my user but i can't. I read these topics, but they doesn't work for me.

[How to change credentials for SVN repository in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914895/how-to-change-credentials-for-svn-repository-in-eclipse)

For example, my system doesn't have the svn.simple file which mentioned in this answer.

And this question:

[SVN change username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671662/svn-change-username/9391129#9391129)

When i want to use svn, it says that :

```
'/home/chavosh' is not a working copy
```

What should i do?!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ask your friend to change his/her password. The next time you try to access the repository, you will be asked to provide username or password.

Alternatively, you could clear the cached credentials. There are two ways to do this depending on what client adapter, the plugin is using.

To find out which client adapter is used:
Go to Windows->Preferences->Team->SVN.
In the Client Interface section, check which adapter is used.

If you are using JavaHL then you need to delete files from the svn.simple directory
This directory is usually located in %AppData%\Subversion\auth. (Go to command promt and echo %AppData% to find out location of the AppData directory)

If you are using SVNKit then you need to delete the .keyring file from eclipse configuration directory.
On my workstation the location of this .keyring file is \configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime

Comment: Thanks a lot, in the \configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime was no file, so I delete the whole folder and it works for me, thank you.

Answer (score 19):

In windows :

1. open run type %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple
2. this will open svn.simple folder
3. you will find a file e.g. Big Alpha Numeric file
4. Delete that file.
5. restart eclipse.
6. Try to edit file from projct and commit it
7. you can see dialog asking userName password

It worked for me.... ;)

Answer (score 15):

**1. Goto window->show view->other**

[image: showView]

**2.Select SVN Repositories**

[image: other menu]

[image: SVN Repositories]

**4.Right click the repository that you want to change the users and click `Location properties`**

[image: select location properties]

**5. Finally change the username and password and click `Finish`**

[image: Edit Location Properties Window]

Comment: the only good answer so far, which doesn't suggest to delete some Eclipse files and corrupt Eclipse.

Comment: Good one, but not for all eclipse versions. I couldn't find `location properties` under the repo (right-click). There's only `properties` which does not have the option to change credentials

Answer (score 0):

If you have tortoise client in your machine then removing current user from tortoise also removes it from eclipse. At least it works for me :)
You can remove current user from tortise as described here: [How to change users in TortoiseSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153489/how-to-change-users-in-tortoisesvn)

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Security -> Secure Storage

Then in Contents tab expand [Default Secure Storage] and SVN. Now delete these values.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqZWw.png)

Tested in Eclipse Luna.